# How do I change the value type (from float to integer) in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am trying to parse an Excel with the output as list of dictionaries. I wish to change the type of one of two columns:

1. Date : Any date format
2. Account - see pic)

[image] from Float to integer (in the excel it has no decimal values)

How do I make it happen so that it is saved permanently for further code on reference of this list of dictionary?

Output of my code is as seen in the picture here:

[image]

I tried various options but unsuccessful in making the change and have it displayed as output.

My code:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('filelocation')
ws = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = []  # The first row with values in column
for col in range(ws.ncols):
    first_row.append(ws.cell_value(0, col))
    
# creating a list of dictionaries
data = []
for row in range(1, ws.nrows):
    d = {}
    for col in range(ws.ncols):
        d[first_row[col]] = ws.cell_value(row, col)
    data.append(d)
    
for i in data:
    if i['Account'] in data:
        i['Account'] = int(i['Account'])
        print(int(i['Account']))
print(data)
```

I added the last part to make changes on Account column but it does save the changes in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the syntax is a little off.

```
for element in data: #iterate through list
   for key, value in element.items(): #iterate through each dict
       if type(value) == float:
          element[key] = int(value)
```

This will cast all your floats to ints.

Comment: I am guessing you mean `element[key] = int(value)`. What you are doing is simply changing the loop variable `value` and nothing more...

Comment: I tried this, it still does not change the output of Account. It is still float.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want the account value to be printed as Integer and not float

Comment: You're right, I just edited my response to reflect that. I believe that should work.

Comment: Thank you StevenSolar. It worked. Can you help me with changing the date into readable format please.

Comment: Readable meaning June 3, 2017? Or turning it into a DateTime type object?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the condition `if i['Acount'] in data:`.

`data` is a list of dicts. `i['Acount']` is a float. So the above condition is never met, and any value gets converted to int.

From what I understand from your code you can simply remove the condition:

```py
for i in data:
    i['Acount'] = int(i['Acount'])
```

If you want to generally change all floats to ints, you could change the part where you read the file to:

```py
for col in range(ws.ncols):
    value =  es.cell_value(row, col)
    try:
        value = int(value)
    finally:
        d[first_row[col]] = value
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed the condition. It still does not help me get the output as integer

Comment: What is your output? what do you get when `print`ing `data`?

Comment: print(data) is giving me List of dictionaries...as shown in the pic pasted above